# JQuery effect/animation for loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a very simple effect to let the user know that some background ajax is pending.

I was thinking of simply having "Loading" followed by three dots that animate until the ajax completes.

i.e

```
1: Loading
2: Loading.
3: Loading..
4: Loading...
```

repeat

Does JQuery have any native methods to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

if you need somthing compatible with all browser

find this working fiddel : https://jsfiddle.net/oxkzzrwe/
this plugin should be used like so :

```
$("#randomArea").Loadingdotdotdot({
    "speed": 400,
    "maxDots": 4,
    "word": "Loading"
});
```

**also** find the [ajaxprefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) **native method** to do any thing before an after every ajax request

Comment: And for reference, you "borrowed" it from [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/loading-dots-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer above, there are many great css spinner solutions so use those. I personally would: Inside the event function that triggers the AJAX call, simply use

```
$('.spinner').show();
```

and then in the AJAX success callback

```
$('.spinner').hide();
```

Like this, just for example:

(I'm assuming that if you know how to use AJAX, you can work out how to make a CSS spinner. There are lots of resources and plugins available.)

```
$('.ajax-trigger').click(function () {
    $('.spinner').show();
    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://test.blah.com/test.php',
       data: {
          format: 'json'
       },
       error: function() {
          $('.spinner').hide();
          $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
          $('.spinner').hide();
          $('#info').html('<p>Success</p>');
       },
        type: 'GET'
    }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many (ajax) loader/spinner animations available both for `jquery` and vanila `javascript`, but personaly i prefer pure `html/css` spinners
(sometimes they require a little bit extra html or special html)

However there are pure `css` spinner animations like [Single Element CSS Spinners](http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/) which employ only a single element (genius!)

Pure `html/css` animations have the **advantage of working WITHOUT javascript being loaded or even activated** in the browser, plus they are **more performant** than pure `javascript` animations (at least most of the time, that is).